# Length of a vector, beginner

Tags: c, function, vector

I had a little issue: I can calculate the lenght of a vector but only if the vector is defined in the same function. When I try to pass the vector to another function it returns a wrong output and I don't understand why.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int len(int vec[]);

main()
{
    int a[6];

    printf("%d\n", sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));
    printf("%d\n", len(a));

    return 0;
}

len(int vec[])
{
    return sizeof(vec)/sizeof(int);
}
```

the output is:

```
6
1
```

why the function `len()` doesn't work? It should return 6 instead of 1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sizeof an array in the C programming language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/sizeof-an-array-in-the-c-programming-language)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because arrays *decay* into pointers to their first elements when passed to a function.

There is no run-time storage of the length associated with the array, so this won't work. Basically for a function argument, a type such as `int a[]` is equivalent with `int *a`, i.e. it's just a pointer.

It's best to simply always pass a length when you need to pass arrays to functions, and you can never have a function like your `len()`. The exception is of course if you store the length yourself in the pointed-at data, like strings do with the terminator character.

As a stylistic point, this code in `main()`:

```
printf("%d\n", sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));
```

is in my opinion better written as:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof a / sizeof *a);
```

With the following noteworthy changes:

- The result of `sizeof` has type `size_t`, which is not an `int`. It's correctly printed by the format specifier `%zu`.
- Note that `sizeof` is not a function, so the parenthesis are not needed in most cases.
- Prefer to reference to variables, rather than repeating type names that may or may not be associated with the variables. `sizeof *a` means "the size of the value that `a` points at".
- Also note that according to [C's operator precedence rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence), `sizeof` binds tighter than `/`, so the expression really means `(sizeof a) / (sizeof *a)`, which is the desired result.

Comment: write a function that calculate a lenght passing it a lenght seems a bit useless :) but i understand. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Your `len` function takes as an argument an array of unspecified size, in which case it is treated as just a pointer type (in your case, `int` pointer).  On your particular platform, the size of the pointer is the same as the size of an `int`, so `sizeof(vec)/sizeof(int)` is  1.

If you specify explicitly the length of the array argument, then your size calculation will behave as expected -- but you the function will then only take array arguments of exactly that length.

See also: [C++ arrays as function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867783/c-arrays-as-function-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

Because `int len(int vec[])` is in reality a `int len(int *vec)`. Inside of `len` the variable `vec` is seen as a pointer, thus `sizeof vec` returns the number of bytes needed for saving an address.

Note that `sizeof` is an operator, not a function. That means that the values retured by `sizeof` are calculated at compile-time.