# Passing array as arguments in C++

Tags: c++

I was making a try in passing C++ arrays as arguments in C++ and encountered some problems. I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867783/c-arrays-as-function-arguments) and still wasn't able to solve the problem.

```
C++
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void comb(int a[])
{
    int alen = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a);
    cout << alen << endl;
    /* Since 'I' know the size of a[] */
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    cout << a[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{ 
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    comb(a);
}

Output
2
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

My question is how come the size of the array is getting calculated as 2?

Comment: How come the output is 2?

Comment: If the size of a pointer is twice the size of an `int`

Comment: Shouldn't the logic be `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])`?

Comment: @syb0rg, Doesn't matter, really.

Comment: @syb0rg I am accessing that same element using *a

Comment: Read [diffrence between size of pointer and size of array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarr-return/15177499#15177499) I believe it will help you.

Comment: Are you running a 64 bit OS?

Comment: @MGZero Yes, its 64-bit

Comment: Then that answers it.  Your array is degrading to a pointer.  The size of a pointer on a 64 bit platform is 8 bytes.  Drew's answer covers this in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you specify an array as a function argument, it degrades to a pointer. So `sizeof(a)` is the size of a pointer, *not* the (byte) size of the array. You'll need to pass the length in as a separate argument, or use something like `std::vector`.

Comment: Or use a template, or use `std::array`.

Comment: Or an array reference/pointer. But std::vector should be the default. The 1st rule of arrays is "Don't use arrays".
For completion's sake: `void comb(int (&a)[7])` or `void comb(int (*a)[7])`. The `7` can be deduced with a template, as mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you. I have used vector and have implemented it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

C does not store the length of the array in memory, so the called function has no way
of knowing how long the array is.

`sizeof` is evaluated at compile time, unless you apply it to a array literal, you will not get the length of the array.

You may want to consider passing a `std::vector<int>` by reference instead.