# Why is argv[1] an entire word and not a single letter?

Tags: c++, char, argv

I'm learning c++ and one thing I can't seem to find a good explanation of is how char* argv[] works. I understand that it is an array of characters, but from what I understand if you had

```
char myword[] = "Hello";
```

then myword[1] is "e".

So when using argv[], why is argv[1] the entire first argument and not just the second letter of the program name? There is something here I don't understand but I'm not sure what....

Thanks for any explanations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to miss the point that argv (as in `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`) is a pointer to pointer to char, not the char.

Some funny stuff about arrays and pointers. Since a pointer can be treated to an array (provided it points to an array) and arrays can be treated as pointers (technical term for this is *decay to pointers*) an array and pointer can be often used interhargeably.

However, when doing so, one still needs to keep in mind that at certain times, there is a stark difference between array and pointer. One of the most visible (not the only one!) is the difference in their sizes.

For example:

```
char argv[] = "Test!";
char* pargv = argv;

size_t s_argv = sizeof(argv); // equals to 6 - 5 letters of Test! + \0
size_t s_pargv = sizeof(pargv); // equals to whatver size of pointer you have, i.e. 4 or 8
```

Comment: To be pedantic, `argv` is a pointer. But it does always point to an array of pointers - which in turn always point to arrays of characters.

Comment: Aha! That makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: @user2079303, I do agree with this, and I actually considered phrasing it this way, but than thought 'array' will be better understood by OP.

Comment: @SergeyA I just find it amusing that you correct others that `argv[0]` is not an array but pointer since that's exactly as correct (or incorrect) as saying that `argv` itself is an array.

Comment: @user2079303, me too. To alleviate this a bit, I've edited my answer for better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Because `argv` is a pointer to a pointer to `char`s while `myword` is just a pointer.
`myword` is of type `char*` while `argv` is of type `char**`.

Comment: Actually, `myword` is not a `char*` at all. It is in fact, a `char[6]`

Comment: @user2079303 Which is converted to a pointer whenever you start operating on the array.

Comment: Depends on on how you operate on it, but yes, in many contexts an array will decay to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Because `argv` (assuming you mean that one declared as `main()` parameter) is

```
char* argv[]
 // ^
```

and not

```
char argv[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Argv is basically something like this:

[image]

So on the left is the argument itself--what's actually passed as a parameter to `main`. That's the address of an array of pointers. Each of those points to some place in memory containing the text of the corresponding argument that was passed on the command line. Then, at the end of that array there's guaranteed to be a null pointer.

Note that the actual storage for the individual arguments are at least potentially allocated separately from each other, so their addresses in memory might be arranged fairly randomly (but depending on how things happen to be written, they *could* also be in a single contiguous block of memory--you simply don't know or and shouldn't care).

Comment: Out of curiosity - why did you rearrange third and second arguments, complicating the picture?

Comment: @SergeyA: To emphasize the fact that each of those is (at least in theory) separately allocated, and you can't expect them to follow any particular order in memory.

Comment: I see. I like the new arrangments much better, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that [`argv`] is an array of characters

It's not. It's not even an array.

There are no array parameters in C++, see e.g. [C++ arrays as function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2867783/3425536) and [Passing Arrays to Function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14309136/3425536). The `T[]` and `T[N]` syntaxes, iff used in parameter declarations, actually mean `T*`.

So,
`argv` is a pointer to an array of pointers. Those pointers point to arrays of characters.

Answer (score -2):

`char* argv[]` is a double array (or whatever you want to call it), the same as `char** argv`. The object at `argv[0]` will be another `char*`, `argv[0][0]` will be a `char`.

Comment: No, the object at `argv[0]` would be not an array, but `char*`.